# How to extract specific parts of text from a string?

Tags: nlp, text-mining

For example: 
Here is a textual input:

"ALL imagery SINCE 1952
20 MULE T
aerial BOOSTER
& Multi-Purpose Neutralizer.MAY BE â€œAHMFLL |-E SWALL """""" -5 NETWT4LBS1 DZ (65 OZ) 1.84 kg

"
Output desired:
4 LBS
65 OZ
1.84 kg
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a specific pattern which can be detected by numbers and after that a unit name with two or three letters.
In the other words, detect numbers first, and then find numbers which after of them there is two or three letters.
Moreover, you can check these letters are in a predefined list of units or not.

Comment: Thanks. new to NLP area. Should i use regex followed by checking for a list of terms (for the following text)

Comment: @user44207 Yes. You can find a lot of sources in stackoverflow to find numbers in a text.